# C++ make list with certain values from doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have problem with my doubly linked list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};


void printList(node* head);

void main(int args, char** argv) {
    int x;
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    node* n;

    n = new node;
    n->value = 1;
    n->prev = NULL;
    head = n;
    tail = n;

    cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cout << "Enter element value: ";
        n = new node;
        cin >> n->value;
        n->prev = tail;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    tail->next = NULL;


    system("pause");
}


void printList(node* head) {
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->value << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**Q1 -** How can i find index of first negative element in doubly linked list?

**Q2 -** How to make new list from all negative elements in doubly linked list, and than print new list(negative elements) and doubly linked list(without negative elements)?

Comment: ***How can i find index of first negative element in doubly linked list?*** Hint: the iteration will  be the same as your `printList()`. Instead of printing the value at each node compare to 0..

Comment: ***How to make new list from all negative elements in doubly linked list*** You add elements to a second list the same way you added them to the first. Remember you will need a second head pointer.

Comment: ***and doubly linked list(without negative elements)?*** You can make a 3rd list if you want. Although if all you want to do is print the positive or negative numbers then you only need 1 list with a comparison in the print function(s). You could make a `printPositive(node* head)`, a `printNegative(node* head)` ...

Comment: I cant use only one list. My task says that i need to make second list for negative elements. @drescherjm

Comment: I already told you how to make a second list and how to iterate over the original list finding the negatives. You know how to add to a list so all you need to do is put these concepts together in 1 function. Think  about how it would work with pen and paper..

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code but it should give you good start.

```
class LinkedList {
public:
   LinkedList();
   void insertHead(int val) {
     node* n;
     n->value = val;
     n->next = head;
     n->prev = tail;
     head->prev = n;
     head = n;
   }
   void insertTail(int val) {
     node* n;
     n->value = val;
     tail->next = n;
     n->next = head;
     n->prev = tail;
     tail = n;
   }
   LinkedList makeNewList(int i) {
     node* n = head;
     LinkedList *newList = new LinkedList();
     while(n->next != nullptr && n->next != head) {
        if (n->value < i) {
            newList->insertHead(n->value);
        }
        n = n->next;
     }
   }
private:
   node* head = nullptr;
   node* tail = head;
}
```